# How to register Zend_Log in the bootstrap of a ZF 1.8+ application?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-log

So I want to start logging in my Zend Framework application. I want to register the logger somewhere in my bootstrap so that I can easily access it from any controller action. I think this should be a simple thing that has been done before, but how can I do this?

The documentation shows something like this, but I don't want to create a new Zend_Log every time I want to log something:

```
$writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('/path/to/my/log/file');
$logger = new Zend_Log($writer);
$logger->log('Informational message', Zend_Log::INFO);
```

### Solution

This is what I came up with. Thanks for the reminder about Zend_Registry!

```
// in /application/Bootstrap.php
protected function _initLogger()
{
    $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Stream('php://output');
    $logger = new Zend_Log($writer);
    Zend_Registry::set('logger', $logger);
}

// in controller actions
$logger = Zend_Registry::get('logger');
$logger->log('message');
```

Comment: I would recommend to use `'Zend_Log'` name of the registry element, instead of `'logger'`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest is to use Zend_Registry to store the log

Use this inside your bootstrap

```
Zend_Registry::set('log', $log);
```

and use this to fetch that log

```
Zend_Registry::get('log')
```

Answer (score 5):

I did nearly the same but logging to a db. Here my code I placed in the Bootstrap

```
public function _initLogger(){

    $resource = $this->getPluginResource('db');
$dbAdapter = $resource->getDbAdapter();
    $columnMapping = array(
        'level' => 'priorityName',
        'priority' => 'priority',
        'message' => 'message',
        'created' => 'timestamp',
        'user_agent'=> 'user_agent',
        'get_vars' => 'get_vars',
        'post_vars' => 'post_vars',
        'ip' => 'ip'
    );

    $writerDb = new Zend_Log_Writer_Db($dbAdapter, 'tbl_history', $columnMapping);
    $logger = new Zend_Log($writerDb);

    $logger->setEventItem('datetime',date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $logger->setEventItem('user_agent',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
    $logger->setEventItem('get_vars',print_r($_GET,true));
    $logger->setEventItem('post_vars',print_r($_POST,true));
    $logger->setEventItem('ip',$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);

    Zend_Registry::set('logger', $logger);

}
```

And access it from anywhere like :

```
Zend_Registry::get('logger')->log('log emergency message', Zend_Log::EMERG);
Zend_Registry::get('logger')->info('just logging some information');
```

Hope this helps to ;)

Comment: Nice! I like that. I am not familiar with `$logger->setEventItem()`. What does that mean exactly?

Comment: `setEventItem` adds mandatory always-present elements to every event you're logging

Answer (score 2):

Like this maybe;

```
/*
 * In case of need to change Log object
 * 
 * $options['writer'] = Zend_Log_Writer_...();
 * 
 * @param array $options Configuration options
 */
protected function _initLog(array $options = array())
{
    $writer = new Zend_Log_Writer_Null();

    if(array_key_exists('writer', $options))
    {
        if($options['writer'] instanceof Zend_Log_Writer_Abstract)  {
            $writer = $options['writer'];
        }
        else    {
            if(class_exists($options['writer']))    {
                $writer = new $options['writer'];
            }
            else    {
                throw new H2B_Exception("Writer class not found", H2B_Messages_Generic::OBJECT_NOT_FOUND);
            }
        }
    }

    $logger = new Zend_Log($writer);

    return $logger;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Having just written a logging class, maybe by sharing what I did you'll get some ideas...

From index.php (on ZF 1.62) I call a static method from a class in my library, it determines whether you're in dev or higher, then gives you an appropriate logger. In dev it will log to Firebug, in stage+ it will log to file...I plan to add an emergency logger that will send email alerts on bad events like a failed query which might indicate an attempt to inject into the dB...

Then in my base Controller from which all controllers extend, I call the logger. This way all actions need only one line to talk to the logger...e.g. $this->_logger->debug('test');

Saving one line may not seem like a big deal, but when you're just spitting out debug messages that you plan to delete a minute later, it's really annoying to remember syntax and type both...

Also, by spitting out to firebug, you don't have to deal w/ messing up layout nor removing the debug message right away, since it'll never show in production.